# Read a BLOB in Oracle from Node.js

Tags: javascript, oracle, node.js, blob

I've connected my web server node.js to Oracle, and I've already select some data from de database.

There is no problem when I select data types like string or int, but I need to read some BLOBs too (called PARAMETERS in my database).

- First problem: The size of the BLOBs stored in the data base is 37000 bytes, but the size max of the buffer is 2000 -->Solution : I've only selected the first 2000 bytes
- Second problem: The result is an array, but I think that it's empty or I'm not able to read the data inside --> Solution?

Does anyone know how to read a BLOB with the node.js-Oracle module?

Thank you  very much!

```
db.connect({ "hostname": "xxx", "user":"xx", "password": "xx", "database": "xx"},     function(err, connection) {
            if (err) {
                return console.log("CONNECTION ERROR: " + err);
            }
            else{
                console.log('Connected to Oracle ');
                connection.execute('SELECT utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(dbms_lob.substr(PARAMETERS,2000,1)) FROM records WHERE records.id = 1', [], function (err, rows) {
                        if ( err ) {
                            console.log('error: ' + err);
                        }
                        console.log('Parameters= ' + rows);
                        socket.emit('response:record', {'record': rows});
                 });
                 connection.execute('SELECT records.name FROM records WHERE records.id = 1', [], function (err, rows) {
                        if ( err ) {
                            console.log('error: ' + err);
                        }
                        socket.emit('response:name', {'record': rows});
                        console.log('name= ' + rows);
                 });
               connection.close();
               }
});
```

The result is :

Connected to Oracle
Parameters =  [object object]
name = [{NAME: ARD}]

Comment: which module do you use exactly (oracle or db-oracle)?

Answer (score 0):

You shall update version of your [oracle](https://npmjs.org/package/oracle) module to the latest one - 0.3.4
It has better support for BLOBs.

You can do it as following:

```
npm update oracle
```

Comment: I've updated my oracle module but I still have some troubles with my blob...Now, I'm trying to extract the blob (OCCIBLOB type) calling to a stored procedure from Oracle (Call ReadBasicBolb). This method is defined in outparams.js (see github.com/feedhenry/node-oracle/blob/master/test/outparams.js) but I don't reach the expected results. In fact, each time I execute the call I see different results in a random way......Anyone knows why the OOCIBLOB it's the only method wich not have a validation test in outparmas.js? Maybe the OCCIBLOB hasn't been validated?

Comment: You are referring to a forked, 6 months old version of original module: https://github.com/nearinfinity/node-oracle Could you use original one? Check version of the module you have - it shall be oracle@0.3.4. It supports BLOB what I mentioned in the answer

Comment: Yes, I use 0.3.4. and thanks to this I don't obtain empty results any more. However, each time I execute the procedure I reach different values...